# Number of abelian subgroups of $S_8$ of order 16

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $S_8$ be the symmetric group of permutations of an $8-$element set and let $k$ be the number of its abelian subgroups of order $16$. Prove that $k ≥ 1050.$

I think the subgroups of order 16 are generated by two disjoint cycles of order $4$. The number of such cycles is, I think, $\frac{8\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5}{4 }\frac{3!}{2}=1260$. Thus, is the answer proved. Note that I think the disjoint cycles generate an abelian group. Any ideas. Thanks beforehand.

P.S.:This is problem U396 in [Mathematical Reflections](https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-pdf-files/math-reflections/mr-2016-06/mr_6_2016_problems_1.pdf)

Comment: what about four disjoint transpositions?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo thanks for pointing out, but is my reasoning partially correct?

Comment: i think you need to divide that by $2$ one more time, I think it should be $\binom{8}{4}\times 3!^2 /2$

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo how come? the number of cycles of order $k=n\ldots(n-k+1)/k$, isnt it?

Comment: yes, but you want to select unordered pairs of them, so you are counting each pair twice

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo ok thanks, modified the post.

Comment: There is another possibility: a four cycle with two disjoint transpositions. <(1234),(56),(78)>

Comment: @gobucksmath yes, I agree. But, isnt even this partial enumeration sufficient for the problem?

Comment: Oh, and you also forgot to divide by $9$, because every such subgroup is generated by $9$ different pairs of elements.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo could you please elaborate?

Comment: sure, notice that $\langle (1,2,3,4), (5,6,7,8)\rangle = \langle (1,3,2,4),(5,6,7,8)\rangle $.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo but that is included in the formula for disjoint cycles, isnt it?

Comment: yes, but given a specific subgroup there can be many ways to select the cycles.

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo how do you get $9$ different pairs?

Comment: Is this from an ongoing contest? See comment [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092988/).