# Find the number of abelian subgroups with order $15$ in symmetric group of degree $8$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

Find the number of abelian subgroups with order $15$ in symmetric group of degree $8$.

I was trying to find the number of elements of order $15$ in $S_8$ but I think this is not true. Also I have read [this discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2089777/number-of-abelian-subgroups-of-s-8-of-order-16) but have not solved it yet.

Please give me hints or solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, there is no symmetric group of order 8. I guess you want *degree* 8. Every group of order 15 is cyclic. When you already know how many elements of order 15 are in $S_8$, it only remains to count how many are in a given subgroup of order 15.

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki yes it was degree, edited.

Comment: @SouravGhosh thank you..it works...

Comment: $\text{number of subgroups of order $15$}=\frac{\text{number of elements of order $15$}}{\varphi(15) }$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to reason this way.

We know that every abelian subgroup of $S_8$ of order $15$ is cyclic and is generated by an element of type $(12345)(678)$.

In the group of permutations $S_5$ on symbols $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ there are exactly $24$ cycles of length $5$.
Hence, there are exactly $24/4=6$ cyclic subgroups of order $5$.

The set of $8$ symbols can be split into two parts of $3$ and $5$ elements in each parts in $\binom{8}{3}$ ways.

It follows that $S_8$ has
$$
6\cdot\binom{8}{3}
$$
of subgroups of the order of $15$.